# CPU and RAM usage per WHM subaccount

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have a cloud server from a well known hosting provider using WHM and CPANEL for hosting. I have been dealing with capacity issues on a very random occasions but almost once every day.

Under WHM I have several sub-accounts. The problem is that, with what the hosting company provides as statistics the whole Cloud Server is accounted for. Therefore, I cannot pinpoint exactly which sub-account is using how much RAM and/or CPU.

Is there a way to distinguish on resources usage between WHM sub-accounts?

Answer (score 1):

WHM has a tab/report titled "process manager" under the "system health" category. If you type "process manager" on the search box on the top left, you should be able to find that. On process manager, you should be able to see the memory usage of processes and the corresponding users (sub-account). You may have to look at the process manager during load spike times to pinpoint the problematic account.